# PDF Fonts that support Japanese/Chinese Characters () &#144954;

Tags: pdf, unicode, fonts, coldfusion, cjk

I am currently working on an application which generates PDF's. However Some of the Names to be displayed are in both Japanese and Chinese. The problem I ma facing is the currently as I have it I can display (辻直) no issues in the pdf however if I try to display (辻直) is all shows up blank.

Is there anyone on familiar with displaying Japanese in PDF that might help me over come this?

Currently my font family is:

```
div.alternative_name {
    font-family: 'ヒラギノ角ゴ Pro W3', 'Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro',Osaka, 'メイリオ', Meiryo, 'ＭＳ Ｐゴシック', 'MS PGothic', sans-serif, 'Microsoft Yahei', 'cjk';
    font-size:12px;
}
```

With the presence of certain characters the entire filed is blank, All other Japanese characters render correctly when these characters are not present.

The below shows the output of a pdf rendered from html. The html contains Just two divs

1

```
<div style="font-family: ヒラギノ角ゴ Pro W3', 'Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro',Osaka, 'メイリオ', Meiryo, 'ＭＳ Ｐゴシック', 'MS PGothic', sans-serif, 'Microsoft Yahei';">Hii::    &#32;&#38754;&#20498;&#144954;</div>
```

2

```
<div style="font-family: ヒラギノ角ゴ Pro W3', 'Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro',Osaka, 'メイリオ', Meiryo, 'ＭＳ Ｐゴシック', 'MS PGothic', sans-serif, 'Microsoft Yahei';">Hii::    &#32;&#38754;&#20498;</div>
```

The presence of  is the only difference between the two.
As we can see from the below Image, None of the characters get rendered. they only render when this:  is not present.

[Sample PDF Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlumS.png)

Comment: @KJ Hi KJ Thanks for your reply. I cannot attach files however I have added a little more information. let me know if this is more helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes. MY apologies. So In coldfusion we need to use ##. however for html you can use 1. I have tried both methods and will update this now to remove any confusion.

Comment: I had already come across this alternate HTML Element Code, Unfortunately it had the exact same affect for me.  It seems weird. Everything points to Fonts being the issue. For example if I was to pull the styling from those DIVs then none of the Japanese shows up, only the English would show up. However I have been up and down the web now an tried nearly 100 different Asian and Unicode fonts to no affect. Is it an adobe limitation? 
I am not sure in this case but I have notice some other weird behaviour.

Comment: When looking at this again last night, I added a 3rd Div above the first two
Exactly the sam But the content contained only "面倒" Two character that are working perfect as the document is (not HTML elements just the characters this time) 

This time I observed the top (new)line rendered as garbled mess, but the HTML Elements for all 3 div's rendered with the every other character being correct, ONLY this '' character did dot render correctly it in fact rendered a completely different JP character

Comment: I had also considered adobe having issues with Surrogate pairs (this is what prompted me to convert everything to html Elements instead of plain text) But Not all pairs are having issues, In-fact I later discovered some of the working characters will take 3 array positions to store and they all work fine.

Comment: Do you have access to a webfont that supports this?  If so, you could use that webfont with WKHTMLTOPDF to generate the PDF. (This is easy to test locally and is what do in order to support internationalization for Unicode/utf-8 characters.)